# python check if any of parsed string match with array

Tags: python, scrapy

i am scraping website and want to scrape only the content that has the certain keywords.

for example,
keyword = ["dog", "monkey", "cat", "lion"]
while i scrape through the website, if the content has any of the keyword, then i scrape.

so what i did was:

```
descrs = response.xpath('string(//*[@class="...st-content post__content--new-editor"])').extract()

descr = ""
parseDes = descrs.split(" ")
if descrs in keyword:
        for c in descrs:
                c = re.sub(r"[\u00a0\t\n]+", "", c)
                c = re.sub("\s\s+", " ", c)
                c = re.sub(r"[\u2019]", '\'', c)
                descr = descr + c
        curr_post["url"] = response.url
        curr_post["title"] = title
        curr_post["id"] = id
        curr_post["date"] = date_time
        curr_post["Issue description"] = descr
```

however it is giving me duplicated content.
how do i have the loop move to next one once it finds any of the keywords??

Thank you!!

Comment: to get rid of duplicates easiest way is to use set

Answer (score 0):

> however it is giving me duplicated content.

It's hard to interpret your question because

- idk what `descrs` is
- idk how you expects `descrs in keyword` to work, why not `any(k in descrs for k in keyword)` or `keyword in descrs` at least
- what did you get (variable/print/comment/any sign of what's wrong)
- what did you expect (variable/print/comment/anything)

It looks like you've got the same page multiple times when looping over the keywords, but you provided just a bunch of code without any signs of that loop.

> how do i have the loop move to next one once it finds any of the keywords??

The only thing I can guess is that [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) keyword seems to be a thing you're looking for.